# Dynamic Binding and Overriding/Overloading in java

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public abstract class Vector{
    public abstract double norm();
}
public class PlanarVector extends Vector {
    protected final double x;
    protected final double y;
    public PlanarVector(double x, double y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
    public double norm(){
        return Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y);
    }
    public PlanarVector sum(PlanarVector v){
        return new PlanarVector(x+v.x, y+v.y);
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "x=" + x + " y=" + y;
    }
}
public class SpaceVector extends PlanarVector {
    protected final double z;
    public SpaceVector(double x, double y,double z){
        super(x,y);
        this.z=z;
    }
    public double norm(){
        return Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    }
    public SpaceVector sum(SpaceVector v){
        return new SpaceVector(x+v.x, y+v.y, z+v.z);
    }
    public String toString(){
        return super.toString() + " z=" + z;
    }
}

public class TestVector {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        Vector v0 ;
        PlanarVector v1 , v2 ;
        SpaceVector v3 , v4 ;
        v1 = new PlanarVector ( 3 , 4 ) ;
        v0 = v1 ;
        v2 = new SpaceVector ( 2 , 3 , 6 ) ;
        v3 = new SpaceVector ( 2 , 1 , 0 ) ;
        v4 = v3 ;
        System.out.println(v1.sum(v2)) ; //expected output: x=5 y=7 realoutput: x=5 y=7 (v1 can only use PlanarVectorMethods because its dynamic and static type is PlanarVector)

        System.out.println(v2.sum(v1)) ; //expected output: x=5 y=7 realoutput: x=5 y=7
        System.out.println(v2.sum(v3)) ; //expected output: 'x=4 y=4 z=6'  realoutput: 'x=4 y=4'
        System.out.println(v3.sum(v2)) ; //expected output: 'x=4 y=4 z=6'  realoutput: 'x=4 y=4'
        System.out.println(v3.sum(v4)) ;
        System.out.println(v1.norm()) ;
        System.out.println(v2.norm()) ; //expected output: sqrt(13) realoutput: 7

   

    }
}
```

Can someone explain me why v2.sum(v3) in "System.out.println(v2.sum(v3))" doesn't use the subclass method ?
I know the static type of v2 is PlanarVector but its dynamic type is SpaceVector
same goes for  System.out.println(v3.sum(v2)),  static and dynamic type of v3 is SpaceVector and v2 is considered planarVector here ? Why?!
and the last System.out.println(v2.norm()) considers v2 as SpaceVector this time ... what is happening ?!
I have a last question too, Superclasses cannot use subclasses methods even tho it is an instance of the subclass right ? what happens if the method is an overrided method in the subclass, why the superclass can now use it (and uses the subclass implementation)?

I'm asking a question about java fundamentals, expecting simple and clear answers with examples.

Comment: "Can someone explain me why v2.sum(v3) in "System.out.println(v2.sum(v3))" doesn't use the subclass method" - because the subclass method doesn't *override* `sum`, it *overloads* it, because the parameter type is different. I strongly advise you to use the `@Override` annotation when you're trying to override a method - that way the compiler can tell you when you're not actually doing so...

Answer (score 0):

The method
`SpaceVector sum (SpaceVector)`
in SpaceVector isn't an override of
`PlanarVector sum (PlanarVector)`
in PlanarVector, but just an overload.

Both methods exists in SpaceVector.
It isn't an override because the signature are different (the argument passed isn't of the same type).

Secondly, Java doesn't implement multiple argument dispatch but only single argument dispatch, by using simple virtual tables. In clear, it means that it look only at the first argument to decide dynamically which method to call, and
in Java, the first argument of a (non-static) method is always the implicit this reference. The this reference basically determines in which method virtual table to look at.
Other arguments are always resolved at compile time and never dynamically.
Some languages implement multiple argument dispatch, but not Java.

If you put both information together, you can understand why the actual method called isn't the one you expected:
you pass an object of declared type PlanarVector, so the method called is `PlanarVector sum(PlanarVector)`. The compiler don't know, and in fact can't know if you have a reference to a PlanarVector or a subclass.

Try to change the declarations of v2 and v3 and you will see the difference. Also try with the var keyword and observe what happens. It's interesting to experiment by yourself to understand.

If you want your code to work like multiple argument dispatch, you will need to implement the well known visitor pattern.